# How can I invert a gamepad button to avoid RSI?

Tags: pc, controllers, health, slipstream

The driving game [Slipstream](https://www.gog.com/game/slipstream) requires nearly uninterrupted pressing of my Logitech Dual Action gamepad's "gas pedal" button for minutes at a time.
My physical therapist agrees that my immersion in the game, my inability to squeeze that button no harder than required, is what's given me my first Repetitive Strain Injury (this was once called [Pac Man Thumb](https://atariage.com/forums/topic/22125-arthritis-of-the-thumb/).)

**Can I invert that key binding,** so squeezing that button means *releasing* the gas pedal?

Or can I buy a different gamepad that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I assume** [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) **can be used for this purpose**:

- It [seems](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/52250-logitech-g13-gamepad/) to support gamepads in general (as joysticks).
- It can be programmed to toggle or hold a certain button, using the information given in [this forum thread](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=11938), especially [the last answer](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=176236#p176236) on the first page.
- [Here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#Joystick) is a list of the buttons you might want to refer to (ranging from "*Joy1 through Joy32*").

Maybe something like this will get it to work (using <kbd>t</kbd> to toggle, and where <kbd>Joy1</kbd> should be replaced by the right button, which can be found using the script on [this page](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/JoystickTest.htm)):

```
t::
Send {Joy1 down}
KeyWait, t
Send {Joy1 up}
return
```